# How do I get the Yammer Embed Feed Event listeners to work?

Tags: javascript, events, embed, yammer, listeners

From the [documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/feed-events), all you need to hook onto a Yammer embed feed event is to use:

```
yam.on(eventId, callbackFunction, [context]);
```

Which I've done using the eventIDs they have supplied, so my code ends up looking like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    yam.connect.embedFeed({
        container: "#embedded-comments",
        network: "mynetwork",
        feedType: "open-graph"
    });

    function alertMe() {
        alert("Loading Completed!");
    }

    var nothing = "";

    yam.on('/embed/feed/loadingCompleted', alertMe(), nothing);

</script>
```

Only that the `alertMe()` function gets called immediately, before the page has even loaded. Changing the eventID to something invalid shows the same behaviour, so I'm starting to think I'm missing something here.

Any ideas what could be causing the events to fire immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working by passing alertMe as a reference (removing the parentheses). I was seeing the events firing instantly due to them being executed as they were being read.

Quite a silly mistake, but being a javascript beginner I'm bound to make a lot of these :)

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
yam.on('/embed/feed/loadingCompleted', alertMe, nothing);
```